# Passing an instance of a System.Web.UI.Page to Server.Execute or .Transfer method yields a blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, httphandler

I have customized my `Debt : System.Web.UI.Page` (WebForms) class to have a property of type `Consumption`, which is initialized through the constructor.

```
public class Debt : System.Web.UI.Page {
     public Consumption Consumption {get;set;}
     public Debt(Consumption consumption) => Consumption = consumption;
     ...
}
```

I have a handler, which decides based on some parameters whether to transfer the request to the "Debt" page, or the "Add" page. But if we transfer to Debt page, I'd like to pass a Consumption object thru the constructor, like this:

The handler (*.ashx):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HtmlContext context) {
     Consumption c = [...retrieving the consumption...];
     IHttpHandler handler = new Debt(c);
     context.Server.Transfer(handler, false);
}
```

The transfer happens, but I receive a blank page, instead of the expected "Debt" page.

I've tried with `Execute()`, which requires a `TextWriter` parameter, but I couldn't force the `ProcessRequest` method of the Debt page to output its rendered HTML content (so that the `TextWriter` parameter of `Execute` can consume the output).

I want to avoid `Response.Redirect`, as I want these two pages, "Debt" and "Add" accessible only thru a handler, not by typing them to the browser.

Comment: You can't write `new Debt(c)` because that's not the correct type to instantiate. At runtime, ASP.NET converts your .aspx markup into a dynamically generated subclass of `Debt`. That subclass will have an empty constructor.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do dependency injection in webforms. Here is the good news. In .net 4.7.2, DI is added in webforms. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/02/05/announcing-net-framework-4-7-2-early-access-build-3052/

Comment: Can I then instastiate the generated `debt_aspx` class and set its Consumption property to `c`? At which lifecycle event is the generated subclass created? Or is it done at compilation?